# Why parallel for loop fails in python

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing

I want to do a for loop parallel:

```
def multiple(a, b):
    return a * b
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(multiple)(a=i, b=j) for i in range(1, 6) for j in range(11, 16))
```

But it gives me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tiantian/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/Users/tiantian/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 603, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "/Users/tiantian/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <genexpr>
  File "/Users/tiantian/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 183, in delayed
    pickle.dumps(function)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: I would comment, but not enough rep ;/*

First of all you should clearly mention that you are using `joblib`,

Second, I tested this code using `joblib==0.10.3` in interactive interpreter with python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 - works perfectly.

Error you are getting is thrown when `joblib` is testing if the function you are trying to use can be pickled (only *pickable* objects can be multiproccessed), is this full code besides imports? Aren't you messing with `multiple` somewhere on the way?

It also reminds me some case about multiprocessing not working properly when you're using interactive interpreter, maybe write it as a script if you haven't already?